# Edit String in library archive (filename.a)

Tags: c, linux, hex, static-libraries

I has been compiled C library, and I have file library example filelib.a , and I want to edit string in filelib.a because my source code C has been removed from my PC, I want to edit string there, In file filelib.a there are string "article seen".
If I grep:

```
$ grep -R "/etc/resolv.conf" *
Binary file filelib.a matches
Binary file filelib.so matches
```

So there are string "/etc/resolv.conf" in file filelib.a and filelib.so.
How to edit and replace string in binary file filelib.a and filelib.so, example I want to replace string "/etc/resolv.conf" to "/system/etc/resolv.conf"

I have edit with hex editor BLESS, but if I use this lib I get error:

```
could not read symbols: Malformed archive
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm using linux ubuntu.

Thanks.

Comment: Change the code & rebuild is the usual option. What's preventing you from doing that?

Comment: My code has been disappear

Comment: Lessons for the next project you'll be working on: **backup your source code** (and your work), and use some *version control system* like `git`. Better yet, make it some free software (e.g. GPLv3+ license), and publish it thru http://gitorious.org/ or http://github.com etc.... Losing by accident your own source code is usually unprofessional.

Answer (score 3):

If you **really don't have the slightest chance to obtain/recover the soirce code,** amd the new string is equally long as or shorter than the original one, you can open the archive using a hex editor, binpatch the string and pad with zeroes if it's shorter than before (there must always be at least one terminating zero byte).

If you want to change the string to something longer, that's not easy - your best chance would be perhaps to extract the archive, disassemble the object file in which you want to make changes, change the assembly, then reassemble it and use `ar` to update the modified object file in the library.

Comment: Hi I have edit with hex editor BLESS, but if I use this library I get error could not read symbols: Malformed archive
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status. Where is wrong, I just replace string "/etc/resolv.conf" to "/system/etc/resolv.conf"

Comment: @LorenRamly Firstly, don't double-post identical comments. Secondly, if the library is corrupted, then you did something wrong, not the hex editor. Third, google the usage of `ar` or run `ar --help`.

Comment: OK, I has been doing --help, but not information about replace string, Just replace object, but my code C has been dissapear :(. So i cannot compile object again.

Comment: @LorenRamly `ar` in itself won't replace strings for you, that's not what I am saying. You have to extract the object file the string is in, disassemble it, modify the string, reassemble it and put it back to the archive (`ar` is helpful only for the last step).

Comment: I have extract all object to directory with: `ar x libc.a directories/` and after that I edit file __dns.o replace string "/etc/resolv.conf" to "/system/etc/resolv.conf" with hex editor, After that I use `ar r libcnew.a directories/*` , and I have file libcnew.a , But it not use. I get much error, example error "(getaddrinfo.o): In function `getaddrinfo'"

Comment: @LorenRamly Frankly, don't you **read** the answer? I state it *twice* that you can't just binpatch the file if the new string is longer, for obvious reasons. You have to extract the object file, disassemble it, change the string in the assembly, reassemble it and then put it back to the archive. What do you fail to understand in this?

Comment: I not understand how to disamble and resamble again object file.

Comment: @LorenRamly Using a disassembler and an assembler.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the string you want to change in is shorter or equal to the one in the binary file, you can just use a hex editor and substitute the string, and replace any reaming characters with `\0`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the [Bless Hex Editor](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/bless/) should do the job for you.

Just make sure that you **do not change the length of the file**. It *may* be possible to use a *shorter* string than the old one, if you insert a `'\0'` terminator, but that all depends on how the program uses it, so I'd recommend against.